# How to limit access to ElasticBeanstalk port 80 from internal zone only?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have ElasticBeanstalk environment which should be exposed to the Internet via HTTPS port but also exposed via HTTP only to some instances inside my cloud. It therefore has 2 listeners. EB auto-sets a "HTTP ANY IP" inbound rule for the LoadBalancer security group of my env.

Now, I have defined a Route 53 alias to my EB environment, e.g. "myenv.company.internal". Next, I `curl "http://env1.company.internal"` from some EC2 instance and it works only if the inbound rules are "HTTP ANY IP". If I try to limit HTTP only to the security group of my EC2 instance, that instance cannot `curl`.

How do I limit HTTP port 80 access of my EB environment only to some other security group in my cloud?

Comment: You can't reference security groups as a reference for internet traffic. Not sure what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Clarifying: I want my beanstalk env to be accessible via 2 ports: https from anywhere and 80 only from EC2 instances that belong to a certain security group. I tried setting a port 80 inbound role like "HTTP port 80 only for sg-12345678 group" but instances in that group were unable to curl into the EB env

Comment: The port 80 should be accessible directly on the EB instance, or through internet facing ALB?

Comment: Through the ALB (that's why I use a Route53 alias). The EB instances themselves belong to a different sec group which only allows the ALB to access them. The inbound rules I tried were only on the ALB sec group

Comment: `http://env1.company.internal` is from R53's private hosted zone?

Comment: yes, it is, and the record is of type "alias" to beanstalk ALB

Comment: I don't think it will work. The domain `env1.company.internal` will probably resolve to public IP address of the ALB. You can check it with `dig env1.company.internal`. SGs don't work over the internet, it all must be private traffic within the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I limit HTTP port 80 access of my EB environment only to some other security group in my cloud?

You can't do this for internet facing ALB. If you setup `env1.company.internal` private hosted zone record for public ALB, it will just resolve to **public IP addresses** of the ALB.

Therefore, you **can't use SGs** in ALB SG ingress rules to limit traffic. That's why it works with `HTTP ANY IP`, but not with reference SGs.

If you want to overcome this issue, you can attach an **Elastic IP** to your other instance, and limit port 80 on ALB to only allow connections from the Elastic IP address. For more instances, you can use **NAT gateway**'s public IP address.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't assign an elastic IP because the other EC2 instances are also beanstalk instances and keep changing. Is there maybe a way to limit by IPs of my VPC (assuming there's something like a "public ip" for it?), for example? Not ideal but at least port 80 won't be exposed.

Comment: @SagiMann The easiest would be just to connect directly to EB instances using their private IP address. Is there reason why you want to use public ALB port 80, for private traffic only? I can't understand the rationale for this.

Comment: it is because I need load balancing for my http requests, even though they are coming from within the cloud. The instances themselves keep changing under Beanstalk, I can't really list or reference them and their IPs anywhere.

Comment: Are the EB instances in private subnet, behind NAT? Then you can just whitelist NAT's IP address in your ALB. Then it does not matter how many other instances you have or what are their IP addresses.

Comment: They are in my VPC. They have some subnet ID but it's managed automatically I think, being part of a VPC, though I'm not sure how to try this

Comment: @SagiMann If you used EB wizard, then all instances will be in default VPC with public subnets. But I still struggle to understand, port 80 is HTTP. So you want to use port 80 over the internet, in plain text?

Comment: no, I was looking for a way to use my EB env through HTTPS-only from any IP and through HTTP from hosts inside my VPC, using a route 53 internal DNS name

Comment: @SagiMann Sadly, its not doable with internet facing ALB. You need internal ALB for that.

Comment: does it mean I need to setup my own ALB instead of the one EB provides?

Comment: @SagiMann I would consider re-architect your setup. I would place EB instances in private subnets. Leave your ALB for internet traffic as it is now. But setup second ALB, internal-internal only, for port 80 for the instances. Don't know if there is any easier way, based on your requirenemnts.